# What does the “yield” keyword do in Julia?

Tags: julia

What is the use of the `yield` keyword in Julia and what does it do? I have seen it used a few times in Python and then in Julia but it seems to be used in very different contexts in Julia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike in Python, [where the yield keyword function similar to the return keyword but for generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do), the `yield` keyword function in Julia is part of the tasks interface. [From the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/parallel/#Scheduling-1):

```
yield()
```

> Switch to the scheduler to allow another scheduled task to run. A task that calls this function is still runnable, and will be restarted immediately if there are no other runnable tasks.

Comment: You may also want to note that it's just a function, not a keyword.