# How to write a simple function in Julia similar to a function with yield keyword in python

Tags: julia, yield

I have a very simple function to illustrate yield keyword in python:

```
def simpleFun():
    yield 1 
    yield 2 
    yield 3 
x=simpleFun() 
print(x.next()) 
print(x.next()) 
print(x.next())
```

which will output

```
1
2
3
```

How to write an equivalent function in Julia.

I have seen the 'yield' keyword is used in a different context in Julia.
Ref : [What does the “yield” keyword do in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60743322/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-julia)

Comment: `yield` essentially creates coroutines, which Julia supports.  The closest equivalent is @tasks.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894052/julian-way-to-do-pythons-yield-and-yield-from (Julia experts: is the information there still relevant enough that this question should be closed as a duplicate?)

Comment: Related packages: https://github.com/jolin-io/Continuables.jl https://github.com/JuliaDynamics/ResumableFunctions.jl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [julian way to do python's yield (and yield from)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894052/julian-way-to-do-pythons-yield-and-yield-from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that follows the style of the Python code:

```
julia> using ResumableFunctions

julia> @resumable function simplefunction()
           @yield 1
           @yield 2
           @yield 3
       end
simplefunction (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = simplefunction()
var"##simplefunction_FSMI#293"(0x00)

julia> print(x())
1
julia> print(x())
2
julia> print(x())
3
```